# call extended class variable in parent in ECJ

Tags: java, variables, parent-child, extends

I am using ECJ (an evolutionary algorithms package) and I want to call certain variables that are in an extended class but I can't figure out how to get to them from the problem class.

As you can see in the problem class below I want to be able to call the variable x in the NetworkGene class but it doesn't work because I end up in the VectorGene class in which I can only call variable y.

```
class Problem {
  double fitness = 0;
  public void evaluate(final Individual ind){
    if(!(ind. instanceOf GeneVectorIndividual)){
      state.output.fatal("Not a GeneVectorIndividual",null);
    }
    fitness = 0;
    for(){
      fitness += ind.genome[i].x;
    }      
  }
}

public abstrabct class VectorIndividual extends Individual{
}

public class GeneVectorIndividual extends VectorIndividual{
  VectorGene[] genome;
}

public abstract class VectorGene implements Prototype {
  double y;
}

public class NetworkGene extends VectorGene{
  double x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic polymorphism problem.

The quick and dirty solution is this: in the `for` loop in class `Problem`, add these lines

```
if (ind.genome[i] instanceof NetworkGene) {
    fitness += ((NetworkGene) ind.genome[i]).x;
}
```

But probably there's a design problem you need to solve:

Why is `ind.genome` an array of VectorGenes instead of NetworkGenes?

What does `x` represent? Is there something you could express within `VectorGene` like a method `getSomeValue()` which in `NetworkGene` you would implement to return `x` (and in other subclasses you'd implement it to return some other appropriate value)?

Do you really *need* the inheritance relationship between `VectorGene` and `NetworkGene` - does it relate to some difference that you actually need to exploit in the problem you are currently trying to solve? Couldn't you just have a single class containing properties `x` and `y`?

Comment: I am using a standard package and they chose to use a lot of inheritance relationships to make the program applicable to all kinds of problems. The VectorGene object is a standard object in the package and the NetworkGene object is an object I made. This is the standard way that is in their manual. A parameter file tells the program to use the NetworkGene object. I find the whole program to be very confusing and I am not sure how everything is inherited because of the way it is implemented.

Comment: Ah, the joy of frameworks. OK, in that case, if NetworkGene hasn't been designed with some abstract method you could implement like `getFitness()`, then there's not much you can do other than the quick and dirty solution I suggested.

Comment: Even if I add this quick and dirty method I still get the error message that it cannot find symbol (x variable). These variables are just dummies to explain the problem.

Comment: Ok, I solved it by adding a getFitness() method to the VectorGene and NetworkGene objects. Thanks

Comment: OK. I thought you couldn't modify VectorGene because it was supplied by the framework.